# Proof inequality with complex analysis $\csc(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I'm studying complex analysis and i found this problem

$$
|\csc(z)|\le \frac{2e}{e^2 - 1}
$$

Where $z = x + iy$  and $|y|=1$.

I started defining $\sin(x + iy)$ and put it on Euler's function but it doesn't work.
Any tip? Everything will be helpful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|\csc z|$$
$$=|\frac{1}{\sin z}|$$
$$=\frac2{|e^{iz}-e^{-iz}|} \text{(as,$sinz=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}$)} $$
$$\le\frac2{||e^{iz}|-|e^{-iz}||} \text{(as, $||x|-|y||\le |x-y| $)}$$
$$=\frac2{||e^{-y}|-|e^{y}||} \text{(as,$|e^{ix}|=1=|e^{-ix}|$)}$$
$$=\frac2{e-e^{-1}} \text{(as,$|y|=1$)}$$
$$=\frac{2e}{e^2-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition you have
$$
\csc z=\frac1{\sin z}
$$
and
$$
\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\;.
$$
Observe then that $z=x\pm i$ then $iz=\mp1+ix$ and $|e^w|=e^{\Re w}$ for every $w\in\Bbb C$, so you have to distinguish the two cases according with the sign. Il will write the case $z=x+i$:
\begin{align*}
|\csc z|
&=\frac2{|e^z-e^{-z}|}\\
&\le\frac2{|e^{-iz}|-|e^{iz}|}\\
&=\frac2{e-e^{-1}}\\
&=\frac{2e}{e^2-1}\;.
\end{align*}
The other is similar, you just have to "swap" the summand in the reverse triangular inequality.

Comment: I'm relatively a beginner on this topic, the second proof with triangle inequality was more manageable for me, so really thanks! I'm studying with a Churchill and Schaum's book!